# Can a tag be a link without using the `a` tag?

Tags: html

I was just curious to know can a tag like `div` or `h2` or any other tag be a link without using the `a` tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make "div" as "a href" without "a" tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463386/how-can-i-make-div-as-a-href-without-a-tag)

Comment: What's the case of having a link tag without an a tag ? What's the problem with it ?

Comment: If you use a front-end framework like Angular, you can do that such as [routerLink] in angular. But probably it is converted to <a> when compiled.

Comment: the anchor tag is bound to a default behaviour when clicked.. the browser just visits the link specified in its href attribute. But you are free to add a click event listener to any element and code the same exact behviour with window.location.href .. of course breaking accessibility rules doing like that. Screen readers for example have rules to interpret the html document according to standards and if you invent your own standard they will never know

Comment: It depends on the precise definition of "link" that you are using. There's no *good* (i.e. semantic and accessible) way that doesn't use `<a>`).

Comment: Tamás, thanks, it answers my question real well.

Comment: Mehdi Faraji, there's nothing wrong with it, I was just curious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `onclick="window.location.assign()"`

The snippet below addresses styling, tab accessibility, and browser history concerns, but it is invalid by WCAG.

```js
document.querySelector('.link').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    window.location.assign('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  }
});
```

```css
.link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.link:hover {
  color: darkblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1" class="link" onclick="window.location.assign('https://stackoverflow.com/');">
  Fake Link
</div>
```

Comment: (1) This will not be announced as a link by screen readers. (2) You can't tab to it and then activate it with Enter like a link. (3) Search engines will not recognise it as a link. (4) It replaces the current URL in the browser history instead of adding to the history. **That does not behave like a link**.

Comment: it now acts more like a link.

Comment: I wasn't looking for anything that **behaves like a normal link** so this answer is accepted. Now it is even better. Thanks!